# Javascript function works fine expect on mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile-safari

I use a `QR Reader` JavaScript developed by [Lazar Laszlo](https://github.com/LazarSoft/jsqrcode).
Quite a nice script. Everything works fine except on the mobile Safari.

If I use an image which is bigger than 2000x2000 pixel (e.g. iPhone 5 Camera Image), it will return a error `cannot parse qr code`. The same picture works fine on desktop browsers or Android systems.

The error will happen in `line 70: http://cxg.de/_1ac831.htm`

Do you have any idea why I have such a weird behaviour? Maybe that is a storage limit problem or something else.

Comment: What does your JavaScript error console say?

Comment: The console just says: "Unable to find pattern". This is the same code if you "scan" a non qr code like image. :(

Comment: As a follow up, there is a github issue based on my problem on Lazar's account: [Issue](https://github.com/LazarSoft/jsqrcode/issues/5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close this thread: The [issue](https://github.com/LazarSoft/jsqrcode/issues/5) is still open that causes this problematic. I would doubt that this will be an open issue for ever.